# Set value of the radio group model inside ngChange handler

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I have a simple form with 3 radio button with same `name="myNumber"` and a method to handle `ng-change` event

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="number" name="myNumber" value="1" ng-change="handleChange()" /> 1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="number" name="myNumber" value="2" ng-change="handleChange()" /> 2
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="number" name="myNumber" value="3" ng-change="handleChange()" /> 3
  </label>
</form>
```

In the change handler, I simply set the value of $scope.model to "3"

```
angular.module('radioExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.number = "1"; // initial value

    $scope.handleChange = function() {
        $scope.number = "3"; // what I want to do
    };
  }]);
```

Then I try clicking around the radio buttons to trigger the `$scope.handleChange` event to see if it work but since the 2nd click ahead, the result is like this:

- **Expected**: The radio button number 3 keeps being checked.
- **Actual**: All radio buttons are not checked at all.

**Edit 1: Update fiddle example**

I added this `<div>` as a simple log to the screen, the result of `$scope.number` always = "3" which is expected. What's wrong is the checked status of radio buttons

```
<div>
$scope.number = {{number}}
</div>
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/ujem8ndx/2/

Comment: my guess is that this is not what you should be doing with radio buttons, so maybe you need `ng-click` instead (potentially with `$event` and `event.preventDefault()`)

Comment: there might be a conflict between Angular model binding and html form, as in Angular document they not recommend to use "name" in Angular form, see here for more detail https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.2/docs/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D

In plain HTML forms, the name attribute is used to identify groups of radio inputs, so that the browser can manage their state (checked/unchecked) based on the state of other inputs in the same group.

In AngularJS forms, this is not necessary. The input's state will be updated based on the value of the underlying model data.

Comment: @HieuNguyenTrung: but they've never told that we can't use ```name``` attribute and that attribute is marked as optional instead of forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason but when I remove the `name` attribute from the inputs, the problem's solved.

I posted this as an answer because it solved my problem but the `why` question is not answered.